# Read database.yml from inside ActiveRecord migration

Tags: ruby, activerecord

How do I access the contents of `database.yml` inside an ActiveRecord migration? Specifically, I need the value of the `database` key for the database being migrated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
db = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/database.yml")[RAILS_ENV]['database']
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `ActiveRecord::Base.configurations`